# Program that knows what elements you click on website

Tags: programming-languages, web

I'm trying to create a program where i can select the input boxes on website and list them into a listbox. i can use the C and delphi language but neither of them i can do this. I'm not trying to make a whole new browser, but  just want to be able to do this. In a way it is like, when google chrome puts an orange box around the input boxes. it recognizes that it is a box you can type in. How do i recognize with a program what text box i have selected with my mouse? thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into GreaseMonkey for firefox.  It allows you to run custom javascript on web sites, allowing you to transform pretty much whatever you want on the page.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/

Comment: yeah i looked into that, but i not everyone uses firefox so thats why i thought of something outside of it and make it a more general program, which can be used with everything. like a overlay. but its really important that i can get that mouse function in there. matlab has that but thats not a very good program for the project, probably in the C langauge. but not sure. lol